# Chutzpah & Jasmine tests - upgrade to TFS 2017 has broken tests?

Tags: tfs, jasmine, chutzpah

We've been running javascript tests using jasmine and chutzpah for a while now. We just upgraded to TFS 2017. Our C# test run fine, but javascript tests are no longer being found by the TFS builds. (They continue to be discovered and run  from Visual Studio.)

There are two suspicious messages in the build log, but I've found no useful information about either of them:

```
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.dll is built for Framework 4.5.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
```

I don't know what determines the framework version, and I've read that this is a warning and not necessarily an error. That's backed up by the next error, which implies that the test adapter is being used anyway:

```
No test is available in c:\agent\_work\2\s\D\W\packages\Chutzpah.4.4.4\tools\Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

Is there something about the TFS 2017 upgrade that I'm missing? Does anyone have any insight into these two error messages or how to further diagnose them?

Answer (score 0):

We recently created a new javascript test project and got this running on tfs 2017 build. Just had to add the chutzpah test runner nuget package to the javascript test project enabled the vstst test runner to discover the tests.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah/